# Show a modal dialog using primefaces commandLink in a growl

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog, commandlink, growl

I want to put this command Link on my view message so it gets rendered on the growl, and I can open a dialog when clicking that link.

```
<p:commandLink onclick="PF('dlg_new_user').show()" value="Click Here" />

<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" escape="false" />
```

My message:

```
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Title" , message ));
```

I got it working using the solution below, but the content of the growl gets rendered with escaped html and it renders the link after some seconds.

```
String message = "User not found, <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"PF('dlg_new_user').show();\">Click Here</a> to create new user";
```

[image]

For example:

WebPage

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
    <title>Test my Growl Message</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/controlpanel.css   " />
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
    <h:form id="test" prependId="false">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" escape="false" />
        <p:outputLabel>
            No user found!! <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Click Here" action="#{searchMB.searchSPU}" styleClass="botao_form" update=":test, :msgs, :dialog_user" /> to new User.
        </p:outputLabel>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog id="dialog_user" header="New User" widgetVar="dlg_new_user"
              position="center" draggable="true" resizable="false"
              closeOnEscape="true" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true">

        <!-- Dialog content -->

    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

MB:

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


@ManagedBean(name="searchMB")
@SessionScoped 
public class TesteMB {

    private static final String mainMessage = "Username not founded.";
    private static final String link = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"PF('dlg_new_user').show();\">CLCK HERE</a> to create a new user.";

    public String searchSPU(){

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "No register founded" , mainMessage + "<br/>" + link ));
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Break down your question in managable parts. At least two parts in this case

Comment: added the details in my question

Comment: 'My view' is not a view, it is a one liner from some underfined class... Why do you use a commandLink there? Threre is no action or actionListener so WHAT is called on the server? Please... [mcve]

Comment: And if ___"I got it working using the solution below, "___ means it works, what is the problem then?

Comment: @Kukeltje , Initially I wanted to know if it was possible to use a commandLink on the growl to open a dialog (My actions are to be defined later), but I couldn't  set a CommandLink on the message for rendering on the growl. Then I used the <a> tag as described above, to check if I could at least open the dialog, and it works (without actions) but when the growl message is rendered, it shows escaped html at first, and after some seconds it shows the link correctly, so in the end, I'm not able to use either  a command button or basic html there, and I wanted to know if there's any way to do that

Comment: I've added what happens when I use a <a> link there on my post.

Comment: [mcve] otherwise no one is able to even try to reproduce.

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated with usable example above..... only summarize the code and changed the message to English example.

Comment: How is this 'usable'? When is `public String searchSPU()` called? Please create a real [mcve]. Try in a new empty jsf project.

Comment: @Kukeltje I showed the wrong code , I now put the correct, but this work properly. So I analized my code to find the problem and I discovered : In my content dialog I was using "ui : include" to new page with a new dialog , Then the image 1 is my new page  with a new dialog, which I removed.Thanks for all.

Comment: You know what this means do you? The chance of getting help in the future is greatly reduced. So  have been chasing ghosts... Spend my time on bogus code... Next time please, please, please (for ***YOUR*** sake) create a real [mcve]... Seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was using two growls and one of them was generating the wrong html code.